# Hive query from Spark- failed to parse

Tags: scala, hadoop, hive, apache-spark, hiveql

I am trying to do this in spark-shell:

```
val hiveCtx = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val listTables = hiveCtx.hql("show tables")
```

The second line fails to execute with this message:

> warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQl$ParseException: Failed to parse: show tables
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQl$.createPlan(HiveQl.scala:239)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.ExtendedHiveQlParser$$anonfun$hiveQl$1.apply(ExtendedHiveQlParser.scala:50)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.ExtendedHiveQlParser$$anonfun$hiveQl$1.apply(ExtendedHiveQlParser.scala:49)
>       at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:136)
>       at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:135)
>       at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:242)
>
> ...
>   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Conf non-local session path expected to be non-null
>       at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:204)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.getHDFSSessionPath(SessionState.java:586)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Context.(Context.java:129)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Context.(Context.java:116)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQl$.getAst(HiveQl.scala:227)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQl$.createPlan(HiveQl.scala:240)
>       ... 87 more

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Spark are you running this against?

Comment: Is your conf set up properly?

Comment: Oh, and hql is deprecated now in favor of sql

Comment: try with semi-colons - `"show tables;"`. And as the error says `java.lang.NullPointerException:Conf non-local session path expected to be non-null`, your conf is not correct.

Comment: I have added hive-site.xml to conf. Tried including semi-colons. Spark version- 1.2.1

Comment: I rebuilt Spark. But no use. Please help

Comment: If you look at [this commit](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/e189cbb052d59eb499dd4312403925fdd72f5718) to the Spark project you'll see that the status of "SHOW TABLES" in HiveQL has changed recently -- but this AFTER the 1.2.1 release.  Some more clarity in [this commit](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/85ee76d5d9244a8ce165156c7453670f0fb34ae1). It parses for me in Spark 1.2.0 so maybe something broke in the 1.2.1 release.

Comment: @SpiroMichaylov Thanks. I tried doing it with Create table. I am getting the same error. Is it because I missed something during configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the very same error in my Spark application. A sample:

```
trait EventStreamEnrichmentData {

    protected def streamingContext: StreamingContext

    def makeHiveContext() = Try { new HiveContext(streamingContext.sparkContext) }

    /**
    * context needed to talk to the Hive metastore
    */
    @transient private val hiveContext = makeHiveContext()

    private def currentContext: HiveContext = ???  

    private def makeAnagrafica(): Try[AnagraficaTable] = currentContext flatMap ( makeAnagrafica(_) )
    @transient protected var anagrafica = makeAnagrafica()

}
```

Now if you have:

```
private def currentContext: HiveContext = hiveContext
```

if my understanding is correct you are using a context initialized on the driver whereas with:

```
private def currentContext: HiveContext = makeHiveContext()
```

it depends on the caller, it might also be created in the executors.

In our particular case we get the exception in the former scenario, with the driver-initialized context, but details aside the takeaway is to be careful about where the context lives.

I did not investigate further but the exception actually comes from [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/session/SessionState.java).